# use constraints to automatically adjust the spacing ios

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, constraints

hello i am using constraints to show the view as desired horizontally and vertically an it is working well,

But now according to my requirement i have to use constraints in a seance that if i hide(set hidden) any of the placed button or label then remaining buttons or labels have to adjsut automatially.

for ex :- i am using four button in a series with equal spacing(filling the view). Now if i hide one of the button from the code then remaining three buttons should adjust themseleves according to space

I want this:
[image: image with 4 buttons]

to convert to:
[image: this image]

if i hide one of the four buttons.

Comment: adjust them you mean keeping padding the same and increase each button widt equally ?

Comment: yes the either way,like 1.) either adjust the remaining buttons according to space  ) or adjust increasing the button width equally to fill the space......main motive is to fill the space equally so that it will not look odd.

Comment: Can you show code for how you're hiding label?

Comment: @Zaid- i am hide label or button just by simple code  "lblScreen.hidden = YES"..

Answer (score 2):

Instead of hiding the button, you can animate and change it's width constraint to 0. This will probably look better also

i.e something like this:

```
button2WidthConstraint.constant = 0 
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3) { () -> Void in
    self.view.setNeedsLayout()
}
```

Comment: if we set the button width to zero then i guess it will case problem. as the button x coordinate is still the same and causing the no cahnges on teh left of the button....???

Comment: This is true, so you will have to change the x coordinate constraint as well. You can play around with the animations until you get the one you want

Answer (score 2):

This is kinda difficult using autolayout only. Even if you just change the width constraint to 0 you're gonna have to deal with the spacings. You will need to adjust spacing for edge buttons differently then for buttons in middle - when you change width to 0, there's still left and right constraint and you need to determine which one to zero out as well.

One approach is to use `UIStackView` which handles this case automatically for you. You can set spacing and distribution of buttons in storyboard, made little [sample app](https://github.com/libec/StackOverflow/tree/master/08-StackView) so you can see the settings yourself.

After that you just call: `removeFromSuperview` and the `UIStackView` distributes other buttons for you. You can animate the transition as well.

Comment: hi i see that UIStackView is only compatable with ios9 or greater but what about the lower versions. In those case what should be implemented.

Comment: Do you need to have the transition animated? If not I'd just recreate it programatically. If so you'll have to setup constraints between each button to handle every state which is for 4 buttons (kinda) manageable, but otherwise not so smart solution.

Answer (score 1):

i have tried to solve the problem this way, you can change it as per your requiremne. I have taken UIView(you can take UIButton here) and UIStackView(horizontal axis).

```
-(void)createOrUpdateUI
{
//View 1
UIView *view1 = [[UIView alloc] init];
view1.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
[view1.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:40].active = true;
[view1.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:60].active = true;


//View 2
UIView *view2 = [[UIView alloc] init];
view2.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
[view2.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:40].active = true;
[view2.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:60].active = true;

//View 3
UIView *view3 = [[UIView alloc] init];
view3.backgroundColor = [UIColor magentaColor];
[view3.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:40].active = true;
[view3.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:60].active = true;

//View 4
UIView *view4 = [[UIView alloc] init];
view4.backgroundColor = [UIColor magentaColor];
[view4.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:40].active = true;
[view4.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:60].active = true;


//Stack View
UIStackView *stackView = [[UIStackView alloc] init];
stackView.axis = UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal;
stackView.distribution = UIStackViewDistributionEqualSpacing;
stackView.alignment = UIStackViewAlignmentCenter;
stackView.spacing = 30;


NSArray *viewArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:view1, view2, view3, nil];
for (UIView *view in viewArray) {
    [stackView addArrangedSubview:view];

}



stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
[self.view addSubview:stackView];


//Layout for Stack View
[stackView.centerXAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.centerXAnchor].active = true;
[stackView.centerYAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.centerYAnchor].active = true;
```

}

and it outpit's as :
[image: with three UIViews]

in above code just change line :

```
NSArray *viewArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:view1, view2, view3, nil];
```

to

```
NSArray *viewArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:view1, view2, view3, view4, nil];
```

and output is :
[image: output with four button]

Hope it helps.